# AVPlayer streaming how to play the next mp3 is folder

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, ruby

I have written code in ruby (similar to objective c) which plays an mp3 file from amazon s3 using AVPlayer. I want to be able to play all mp3 file stored in the directory instead of just the one who will i go about doing this?? 
the code i wrote is

```
def buttonIsTapped
p "Button was tapped"

if (@audio_player == nil)
  Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do 
    mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle
    url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mytrackzmusic/music/Nines+-+Loyal+To+The+Soil/", ofType:"mp3")
    #@audio_player = AVAudioPlayer.alloc.initWithData(fileData, error:error)
    @audio_player = AVPlayer.alloc.initWithURL(url)
    @audio_player.play

    @playerIsPlaying = true
  end
else 
  if @playerIsPlaying == true
    @audio_player.pause
    @playerIsPlaying = false
  else
    @audio_player.play
    @playerIsPlaying = true
  end
```

Comment: So what are you asking. You want someone to write the ```Objective-C``` equivalent of of your code?

Comment: i want a solution to playing all mp3 file stored in the directory instead of just the one mp3 file which the code above does. the solution can be objective-c or ruby as the code above is pretty m much the same as objective-c thanks.